# Why does overriding onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle) not work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-activity

Going through android development at the moment and by mistake I overrode `onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` instead of simply `onCreate(Bundle)` and so the activity wouldn't launch. I fixed it by using the correct overload, which was rather difficult to find but that's a different matter.

My question is this: Why didn't that work? Why does overriding onCreate(Bundle, PeristableBundle) not work, i.e. why isn't it called and why does overriding the other overload work?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onCreate(Bundle)` is the usual method you will implement always.

`onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` gets called only if you set the persistableMode, as documentation says:

> `void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`
>
> Same as onCreate(android.os.Bundle) but called for those activities created
>   with the attribute persistableMode set to persistAcrossReboots.

More about `persistableMode`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode

Comment: any ideas how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you create activity with the attribute persistableMode set to persistAcrossReboots as it was mentioned correctly.`onCreate()` version with the second argument is added in Android 21. So it could still not launch!

Here is the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Wow! People answer those questions so fast that I sometimes feel I'm competing with other users.

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales that's true man! But it's good for the Op, different opinions and you don't need to wait for days to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to use OnCreate()
in your BaseActivity class as an abstract.
I am trying to give a real project code snap that will help you to use in your project.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void showNetworkError() {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            R.string.error_network,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

}